# populate jqgrid from database

Tags: json, jquery, jqgrid-asp.net

I am trying to populate a jqGrid with data from database in N-tier architecture. I have looked at the jqGrid code and documentation thoroughly. I need another set of eyes to look at the code below and tell me if I'm missing something.

As you'll see in the code, I have the grid set up to load when the page loads or during a refresh. After the grid loads, I make an Ajax call to get the JSON data (again) and display in a div below the grid.

I see most of the expected behavior. After the page loads, the grid displays the loading indicator, then the Ajax call is initiated and the JSON data is shown below the grid. The problem is that the grid is completely empty. The column headers are correct, but no data appears in the body of the grid.

var mydata;

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var nn = "nilesh";

        $.ajax(

            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "SearchandViewTraineeProfiles.aspx/GetTrainee",
                data: "{'name': '" + nn + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:'text',
                success:
                    function (data) {

                        mydata = data;
                        alert(data);


                    },
                error:
                    function () {

                        alert("error occured");

                    }

            }


            );

    });


</script>
```

//this function for display the Table layout

```
$(document).ready(function () {



    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
        datatype: "text",
        //            colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colNames: ['TraineeName', 'Qualification', 'YearOfPass', 'Percentage', 'Technology', 'Skills', 'BatchName', 'EmailId', 'MobileNo'],
        //            colModel: [
        //                  { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
        //                  { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date" },
        //                  { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
        //                  { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
        //                  { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
        //                  { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
        //                  { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
        //              ],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'TraineeName', index: 'TraineeName', width: 60, sorttype: "string" },
            { name: 'Qualification', index: 'Qualification', width: 90, sorttype: "string" },
            { name: 'YearOfPass', index: 'YearOfPass', width: 100, sorttype: "int" },
            { name: 'Percentage', index: 'Percentage', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
            { name: 'Technology', index: 'Technology', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "string" },
            { name: 'Skills', index: 'Skills', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "string" },
            { name: 'BatchName', index: 'BatchName', width: 150, sorttype: "string" },
            { name: 'EmailId', index: 'EmailId', width: 150, sortable: false },
            { name: 'MobileNo', index: 'MobileNo', width: 150, sortable: false },
        ],
        multiselect: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
        pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "TraineeProfiles"
    });
    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1', { del: false, add: false, edit: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true });




   // takeing the data from user or database
```

//                var mydata = [
//              { TraineeName: "Ganapathi", Qualification: "MCA", YearOfPass: "2012", Percentage: "74.9", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "Asp,Mvc,Wcf", BatchName: "12", EmailId: "kolla.ganapathirao@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689317" },
//              { TraineeName: "Guptha", Qualification: "B.Tech", YearOfPass: "2012", Percentage: "90", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "Asp,Mvc,Wcf,Ajax", BatchName: "12", EmailId: "guptha@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689316" },
//              { TraineeName: "Raju", Qualification: "B.Tech", YearOfPass: "2010", Percentage: "64.9", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "Asp,Mvc,Wcf", BatchName: "12", EmailId: "raju@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689315" },
//              { TraineeName: "Devashish", Qualification: "B.Tech", YearOfPass: "2012", Percentage: "70.9", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "Asp,Mvc,Wcf", BatchName: "12", EmailId: "crucut@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689314" },
//              { TraineeName: "Kalyan", Qualification: "B.Tech", YearOfPass: "2011", Percentage: "78", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "Asp Mvc Wcf", BatchName: "12", EmailId: "kalyan@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689313" },
//                { TraineeName: "Vijay", Qualification: "MCA", YearOfPass: "2011", Percentage: "79", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "Asp Mvc Wcf ", BatchName: "11", EmailId: "ganagaraju@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689312" },
//                { TraineeName: "Gangaraju", Qualification: "B.Tech", YearOfPass: "2011", Percentage: "74.9", Technology: "java", Skills: "jsp springs struts", BatchName: "11", EmailId: "vasntha@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689311" },
//                { TraineeName: "Vasantha", Qualification: "B.Tech", YearOfPass: "2012", Percentage: "76", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "j2EE j2SEE", BatchName: "11", EmailId: "narendra@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689310" },
//                { TraineeName: "Narendra", Qualification: "MCA", YearOfPass: "2010", Percentage: "73.9", Technology: "Java", Skills: "Asp,Mvc,Wcf", BatchName: "11", EmailId: "kolla.ganapathirao@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689309" },
//                { TraineeName: "Praveen", Qualification: "B.Tech", YearOfPass: "2012", Percentage: "74.9", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "Asp,Mvc,Wcf", BatchName: "11", EmailId: "gannipraveen@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689308" },
//                { TraineeName: "Dhanjay", Qualification: "MCA", YearOfPass: "2012", Percentage: "79", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "Asp,Mvc,Wcf", BatchName: "12", EmailId: "dhanjay@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689307" },
//                { TraineeName: "Gowrinaidu", Qualification: "MCA", YearOfPass: "2012", Percentage: "74.9", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "Asp,Mvc,Wcf", BatchName: "12", EmailId: "gowrinaidu@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689306" },
//                { TraineeName: "Swarup", Qualification: "B.Tech", YearOfPass: "2012", Percentage: "59.9", Technology: ".Net", Skills: "Asp,Mvc,Wcf", BatchName: "12", EmailId: "swarup@gmail.com", MobileNo: "8985689305" },
//              ];

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
        jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);



});
```